# In int to float unsafe conversion, what's does *(float*) (&num) do?

Tags: c#, unsafe

I am writing a stream API and it uses a lot of stuff that has to deal with BigEndian/LittleEndian and unsigned vs signed conversions.  I have the following code, which does work.  But I want to know what it's doing, can some ELI5 (explain like I am 5) please?

```
int num = ReadInt();
return *(float*) (&num);

 public int ReadInt()
        {
            return 
                (_memoryStream.ReadByte() << 0x18) |
                (_memoryStream.ReadByte() << 0x10) |
                (_memoryStream.ReadByte() << 0x08) |
                _memoryStream.ReadByte();
        }
```

Now I get what ReadInt does, it's simply turning a LittleEndian into BigEndian. The part that I can't seem to wrap my head around is the `*(float*)(&num)`.

I am guessing it doing some memory shifting of some sort, but not 100% on that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&num` -- "the address of `num`", which is a pointer to an integer.

`(float*)&num` - "the address of `num`, converted to a pointer to float."

This is the memory address of `num`, but the compiler will interpret its content as a floating-point number, not an integer.

`*(float*)&num` - The content of "the address of `num`, converted to a pointer to float" - in other words, take the memory occupied by `num` and read that out as a floating point number.

So if you were to read in the bytes 0x40, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00,
you'd get the integer 0x40100000 = 1074790400 in the memory location 'num'
The address of 'num' would be converted to a pointer to float, and
you'd pull the content of that. The constant 0x40100000, when interpreted
as a float, is 2.25, which is what you'll return.

Comment: Well, that's pretty freaking clever actually. I will eventually explore how to rewrite these to be safe,but for now all my unit tests are passing and I understand what it's doing. Thank you!

Comment: Upon further inspection it seems the built in class BitConverter for .NET is doing the same thing. https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,8640d8adfffb155b

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this to be unsafe C# code, `ReadInt` loads 4 bytes from a stream of BigEndian ordered bytes into the 4 bytes of an `int`, by shifting each byte by 24 bits, 16 bits, 8bits, and 0 respectively (Unlike languages like `C`, `int` in `.Net` is guaranteed to be 4 bytes irrespective of the platform).

As you've guessed, this is likely part of a 'endian-agnostic' library which uses its own proprietary binary serialization format. There will almost certainly be a corresponding `SaveInt` method which will similarly save a 4 byte int into a stream in the corresponding byte order.

Others have already explained, that the code:

```
int num = ReadInt();
return *(float*) (&num);
```

re-interprets the first 4 bytes of the assumed 32-bit `int` (as stored in memory), as a single precision float, which is stored as the IEEE 754 format float layout [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). The technique used is to re-cast the pointer to the address of the int as a pointer to float, instead, and then to dererence the value.

Importantly, `float` is also stored in 4 bytes in .Net (same size as the `int` we've read):

- 1 bit sign
- 8 bits exponent
- 23 bits mantissa

Why? A direct cast from int to float:

```
int num = ReadInt();
return (float)num;
```

would instead of restoring the original 'float' serialized into the 4 bytes, would instead preserve the integral value of the 4 byte int.

Since you say this code comes from a library, it is likely that `ReadInt` is a utility method used in other conversions as well - i.e. other types consuming 4 bytes could also use `ReadInt` method likely do similar post-read 'reinterpretation' of the bytes read.

There is obviously danger in this technique, for example if number of bytes occupied by the returned `int` is insufficient to fulfill larger datatypes, e.g.:

```
int num = ReadInt();
return *(double*) (&num); // Oops.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to explain it step by step:

1. `&` gets a pointer to the object contained in `num`.
2. `(float *)` casts this pointer to a float pointer.
3. `*` de-references this pointer, ie gets the value at this pointer.

Overall, this returns the four most recent bytes in the byte stream as a float.  Though, a you can probably tell, this may not be the best way of coding this.

If I were to hazard a guess, this was written the way it was because a direct conversion between an `int` and a `float` would [preserve the value](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/BitOp/cast.html) rather than the representations of the bytes being read in, which may not be the desired behavior.